# How to build o2scl with visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I want to build o2scl with visual studio. o2scl is a C++ wrapper for a GNU library. Seems like I have to use a configure and make file, some install instructions are available [here](http://o2scl.sourceforge.net/o2scl/html/install_section.html). I guess they are targeted for the gcc compiler. I have never done this kind of thing before. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to do this or point me to somewhere I can get upto speed on building these types of libraries with visual studio?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the O2scl lead developer. I have indeed installed O2scl with compilers other than gcc (Pathscale, Intel C, etc.), but it appears that compilation with visual studio will
take a bit more effort. the O2scl directory and makefile structure is very similar to that used by GSL (GNU Scientific Library), so whatever visual studio files are necessary for GSL 
will probably be adaptable for O2scl. See

http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/computing/gnu_scientific_library.php

for an example of someone who's designed a system for installing GSL in visual studio. 
Note that O2scl requires GSL so you might have to start by installing GSL first. I'm 
away on travel this weekend, but I will check this out next week if I can.

Comment: @Steiner, I have just installed gsl, was a fairly painless process given the visual studio solution .sln file. Not sure what to do now. Maybe the easiest way to install O2scl is just to use gcc (which can be easily installed on windows by installing the Code Blocks IDE).